# Getting error when running jmeter master-slave Error in rconfigure() method

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I have a existing jmeter Master/Slave configuration which works fine. The existing jmeter is 3.0

I installed 3.3 version in the Master server and added the necessary library jar which enabled me to open the existing jmx file.

I copied the exisitng jmeter properties file to the new directory as well. But when I try to run that, I am getting the below error message

```
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

Should I need to install my slave server with 3.3 as well? I tried upgrading the library files, but the jmeter version displayed remains 3.0 even after that. Hence not sure if that is the right way to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the same JMeter version is amust in [Remote Testing step 0](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> Step 0: Configure the nodes
>
> Make sure that all the nodes (client and servers) :
>
> are running exactly the same version of JMeter.
> are using the same version of Java on all systems. Using different versions of Java may work but is discouraged

You should use the download version in all computers there is **no upgrade option** in JMeter